# Importing files in a different directory [PYTHON]

Tags: python, import, interpreter

Say I have an example project with the following structure:

```
-app
    -venv (dir)
    -randomPythonFile.py
    -myPythonFiles (dir)
        -helloworld.py
```

I want to import the file helloworld.py - I know I have to add the directory myPythonFiles to the interpreter path which I can do easily, but how do I push those changes to git so others don't have to manually add it to their paths?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an `__init__.py` file in the directory.

```
from myPythonFiles import helloworld
```